# Do I need both Xiaomi's official unlock app and vbmeta.img for installing an AOSP GSI?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 phone, and I am planning to install an [AOSP GSI from `treble_experimentations`](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/wiki/Generic-System-Image-%28GSI%29-list).

The [documentation for this device in `treble_experimentations`](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/wiki/xiaomi-Redmi-Note-11) states that these are the steps required to install the GSI ROM:

```
fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
fastboot reboot fastboot
fastboot flash system your_gsi_rom_of_choice.img
fastboot -w
```

I am guessing, for the `vbmeta.img`, I am supposed to generate an [empty `vbmeta.img` file](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/224545/90735). And I understand that is required for the system to boot the GSI ROM that I will be installing (otherwise verification will fail).

Looking up on the internet, though, I can see many posts/references about Xiaomi's official unlock tool (which unfortunately only runs on Windows).

My question is: do I need both steps? (i.e.: first unlock with Xiaomi's tool, then flash the empty `vbmeta.img`) or are they exclusive? (i.e.: I could flash the empty `vbmeta.img` without unlocking with Xiaomi's tool and I should be able to flash the GSI).

Also, if they are not exclusive, what does Xiaomi's tool do or why is it required? If flashing an empty `vbmeta.img` is enough, why do people seem to recommend Xiaomi's app in many forums?

Comment: That you need a special procedure or even tool for a bootloader is most likely because of device warranty. By using the unlock tool Xiaomi is able to record which phones have been unlocked. So if you later brick your device and try to get a new because it is still under warranty they can prove you have unlocked your device and deny device change/repair for free.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your comment! ^^ Is that usually something you need to do independently of flashing the `vbmeta.img`? I think I still don't understand what the Xiaomi tool is doing and why is it required to either flash the `vbmeta.img` or the GSI image.

Comment: That should be totally independent. vbmeta.img disables verified boot.

Comment: @Robert If you'd like to add a brief summary as an answer, I'd gladly accept it! ^^ (i.e.: explaining the differences between the effect of unlocking with the manufacturer tool and the effect of flashing the empty `vbmeta.img`).

Comment: XiaoMiToolv2 is available for linux. bootloader unlocking is required for fastboot flash. no need to generate vbmeta, the fastboot command will set disable flag at offset 0x78. system is only flashable from fastbootd, consider sideloading GSI from DSU Loader instead overwriting stock ROM

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for your tips! Would you mind elaborating a bit more in an answer so that I can accept it? ^^

Comment: Sorry I don't own Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 and therefore cannot post valid instructions (I only will post tested confirmed working solution as answer) but I will link some related questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Device says bootloader unlocked but OEM unlock option can enabled and disabled?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231020/device-says-bootloader-unlocked-but-oem-unlock-option-can-enabled-and-disabled)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is suggested to OEM unlock when LinageOS can be installed without it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234315/why-is-suggested-to-oem-unlock-when-linageos-can-be-installed-without-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 02 in the magisk patched vbmeta.img?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221756/what-is-02-in-the-magisk-patched-vbmeta-img)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install GSI on Samsung Galaxy Tab Active3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242677/how-to-install-gsi-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-active3)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks again for the pointers. I need to wait a couple of days (until next Friday) before Xiaomi's tool will let me unlock the bootloader. I will then try the necessary steps to see how it goes. ^^